# How to whitelisting hotspot from the firewall ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, hot-spot

I have to disable the firewall to use hotspot or else other devices can't connect to internet, so I'm assuming hotspot blocked it. I have tried other ways like downgrade `wpa_supplicant` or add new `Network Connections` but no luck so far.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in May I tried the new Ubuntu Mate 22.04, the hotspot didn't work when the firewall (ufw) was enabled. From earlier Ubuntu versions I know that enabling hotspot/ad-hoc adds ufw rules. So I tried to add these rules myself, without luck - no internet for devices connecting to the hotspot. It's ok in 20.04.